# Why phpMyAdmin and MySQL has letters like '?'?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin and MySQL has letters like '?' instead of russian letters

How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding charset
'jdbc:mysql://localhost/flats_flx?characterEncoding=UTF-8'